# Implement like on image

Tags: 7, views

I create gallery list from views 7.x-3.11 with display image and title. When click on title go on content page, its works fine.

I want to display like button on gallery list page of every image.

I try on **flag** with **dlike** module and add field in views of `GLOBAL: PHP` and write code `print flag_create_link("machine_field_name", $row->title)`,
Display Label fine but when click on Label, display popup with A https 500 error occurred.

I also try with [Like Button](https://www.drupal.org/project/likebtn) module but. It show like button only one in one page, i want to like every image.

**My question is how to display like button of every image in page when create page with views.**

Comment: When you get a 500 error there should be a more descriptive error in the logs. What errors are in your logs?

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost certain that adding global: text and using the php text format works.. I remember having trouble with this ages ago so that could be it.

Answer (score -1):

While using [Like Button](https://www.drupal.org/project/likebtn) module, ***in view***:

**Add the field (you created using likebtn widget) to *Fields section* of the view, it will add like button to each image(each content).**

Comment: Not show in each image, display like in only one and rest on LikeBtn.com [?]

Comment: Do your content have multiple images?? One piece of content attached with multiple images, or each content has one image?

Comment: I create gallery listing page with views, Not for content page.

Comment: What I am asking is if you are adding multiple images in one page, or adding separate page for each image?